# Can't manage to make translate_user_role() work

Tags: user-roles, translation, users

I've been looking into wpse archives to solve my problem but I can't manage to do such a thing. I built this code :

```
$args = array('fields' => 'all_with_meta');
$users = get_users($args);
foreach ($users as $user) {
       echo esc_html( translate_user_role( ucfirst ( $user->roles[0] ) ) );
}
```

I made a `print_r()`to see what I get. Everything is fine, I mean I grab user role but it does not translate by itself. Do I need to do more?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>I think your function nesting is slightly muddled; call `ucfirst` *after* translating, like so:</strike>

```
esc_html( ucfirst( translate_user_role( $user->roles[0] ) ) );
```

My bad, completely skipped a beat there. You should instead be using:

```
translate_user_role( $GLOBALS['wp_roles']->role_names[ $user->roles[0] ] );
```

It's unreliable to assume that all role display names are simply `ucfirst( $role key )`. If that still does not work, are you sure the language files you're using have fully translated WordPress?

Comment: right I've changed it but that does not solve my problem

Comment: Answer changed.

Comment: This is not correct anymore for current WordPress version (4.7): Roles are now stored as array, not as object. Correct code is `translate_user_role( $GLOBALS['wp_roles']->roles[ $user->roles[0] ]['name'] );`

Comment: @Philipp Thanks for the heads up - I don't think it was ever an object, was it? As in, I think this answer has never worked!? Answer updated to use `role_names` instead

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `translate_user_role` doesn't work in the front-end currently.

Here is a workaround, you can place this in your theme:

```
add_action( 'init', 'load_admin_textdomain_in_front' )
function load_admin_textdomain_in_front() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        load_textdomain( 'default', WP_LANG_DIR . '/admin-' . get_locale() . '.mo' );
    }
}
```